# Java FX Webview - 2FA verification fails using Web Start

Tags: javafx, webview, google-authentication

I am deploying a Java FX WebView app using Web Start. And I am having trouble authenticating with Google 2 Factor Authentication enabled.

However, It does work correctly for regular authentication (username & password only).

With 2FA: It sends me the Yes/No option to my phone, but once I click yes, the webview doesn't respond.

Now, 2FA in the webview does work when I run the jar locally. It only fails when loaded via Web Start.

The Web Start URL is:

http://aubreigo.info/java/FX-People.jnlp

And the Jar file is located:

[http://aubreigo.info/jav/FX-People.jar](http://aubreigo.info/java/FX-People.jar)

So to summarize:

```
[OK]   Standard Authentication
[OK]   2FA running locally (java -jar FX-People.jar)
[FAIL] 2FA running in Web Start
```

I believe this is a bug in Web Start. Can someone report it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for someone to do something off site, not a question asking for insight or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I have reported this issue to Oracle as a bug with Java Web Start.